# How to solve GET http://localhost/assets/js/leaflet-indoor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404

I am making a leaflet map, it's all working. Then I decided to run it through localhost in htdocs. But the script is not working and I get this 2 error:

```
GET http://localhost/assets/js/leaflet-indoor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost/data/fvrFloor.json net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here's how I import the files:

```
<script src="/assets/js/leaflet-indoor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/data/fvrFloor.json"></script>
```

And here is my project structure:

[My Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oxkp.png)

leaflet-indoor.js is located inside js folder while fvrFloor.json is located inside data folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to add my main project folder in the src attribute just like this:

```
/nav_system/assets/js/leaflet-indoor.js
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).